# Adding BOM (unicode signature) while saving file in python

Tags: python

How can I add BOM (unicode signature) while saving file in python:

```
file_old = open('old.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
file_new = open('new.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-16-le')
file_new.write(file_old.read())
```

I need to convert file to `utf-16-le + BOM`. Now script is working great, except that there is no BOM.

Comment: `for line in file_old: file_new.write(line)` is vastly more memory efficient. And why can't you use any of the numerous software that already does this?

Comment: Text editors have to open file to "save as", and it is pretty big. Other software is shareware, or hard to find. Besides, I'm just learning python. Save by line maybe more efficient, but is more complex.

Comment: If the file is pretty big, that may be all the more reason to convert it line by line -- despite its "complexity".

Comment: And it also depends on how often script is executed. In my case file is 100 mb, converted in <10 seconds once a month.

Comment: @JohnMachin actually had the correct answer here.

Comment: you could use `shutil.copyfileobj(file_old, file_new)` to support large files

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Write it directly at the beginning of the file:

```
file_new.write('\ufeff')
```

Comment: Thank, it is often very hard to figure out such simple thing for first time.

Comment: @Qiao: It's not that simple. See my answer.

Comment: @Ocaso: On Python 2.x the lack of `u` before `'\ufeff'` might cause a Unicode encoding error, specifically if you are explicitly setting the encoding via `codecs.open()`.

Answer (score 41):

It's better to use constants from 'codecs' module.

```
import codecs
f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
```

Comment: This is actually the wrong answer for two reasons. First, @JohnMachin has the write answer. Don't use 'utf-16le', just use 'utf-18'. Secondly (and more importantly) given that the OP's code sets an encoding this won't result in the correct behavior at all. Especially on Python3. You are giving `bytes` to a thing that wants a `str`.

Comment: Err.. 'right', not 'write'. That's what happens when you play with code in one window and write comments in another.

Comment: @Omnifarious: And `utf-16`, not `utf-18`. :p

Comment: @jamesdlin: Oh, oops! I need to do better about typos like that.

Comment: In Python 3, using (default) text-mode `open`, it errors because you toss it bytes, not string, as Omnifarious already hinted. Casting the bytes to a string, as in `f.write(str(codecs.BOM_UTF8))`, gets you `b'\xef\xbb\xbf'` at the start of your file.

Comment: Even if you open a file in text mode, there is a buffered writer, and raw writer underneath. So you can just use them directly to write bytes instead of strings: f = open(filename, 'w'); f.buffer.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE);

Answer (score 37):

Just choose the encoding with BOM:

```
with codecs.open('outputfile.csv', 'w', 'utf-8-sig') as f:
   f.write('a,é')
```

(In python 3 you can drop the `codecs.`)

Comment: or replace `codecs` module by `io`, which works on both python 2 and 3

Comment: This 2017 answer should be voted above the 2011 answers,

Answer (score 22):

Why do you think you need to specifically make it UTF16LE? Just use 'utf16' as the encoding, Python will write it in your endianness with the appropriate BOM, and all the consumer needs to be told is that the file is UTF-16 ... that's the whole point of having a BOM.

If the consumer is insisting that the file must be encoded in UTF16LE, then you don't need a BOM.

If the file is written the way that you specify, and the consumer opens it with UTF16LE encoding, they will get a `\ufeff` at the start of the file, which is a nuisance, and needs to be ignored.

Comment: "Why do you think you need to specifically make it UTF16LE?" winapi can be very particular in what it wants, it only accepts UCS-2 LE with BOM

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation where a 3rd party app did not accept the file I generated unless it had a BOM.

For some reason in Python 2.7 the following does not work for me

```
write('\ufeff')
```

I had to substitute it with

```
write('\xff\xfe')
```

and that is the same as

write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)

my final output file was written with the following code

```
import codecs
mytext = "Help me"

with open("c:\\temp\\myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
    f.write(mytext.encode('utf-16-le'))
```

This answer may be useless for the original asker but it may help someone like me who stumbles upon this issue

Answer (score 5):

For UTF-8 with BOM you can use:

```
def addUTF8Bom(filename):
  f = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8')
  content = f.read()
  f.close()
  f2 = codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-8')
  f2.write(u'\ufeff')
  f2.write(content)
  f2.close()
```

Comment: Solid! Was writing to .csv file in Python which Excel never really opened correctly due to missing BOM, now it's all good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

vitperov's answer for python3:

```
def add_utf8_bom(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
    with codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-8') as f2:
        f2.write('\ufeff')
        f2.write(content)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY IT:

```
def add_bom(file, bom: bytes):
    with open(file, 'r+b') as f:
        org_contents = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(bom + org_contents)
```

USAGE:

```
import codecs

...

file = 'test.txt'
with open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # without BOM
    f.write('A')

add_bom(file, codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)

# TEST
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())  # b'\xff\xfeA'
```

Answer (score 0):

My method of adding BOM is by writing ansi characters 'ï»¿" at the beginning of the file, then open file in UTF-8 and write desired data:

```
# Create file with ANSI encoding
file= open("file.txt", "a", encoding="ansi", errors='ignore')
# Add BOM at the beginning of the file BOM 0xEFBBBF
file.write("ï»¿")
# Close file
file.close()
# Open file in UTF-8 and write data
file= open("file.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
file.write("Write your data here, Enjoy!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write BOM that comes from `codecs` and is not hard-coded as symbols, it is possible to use [Carson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58948073/2893496), but unfortunately it writes a file, and then rewrites that same file after reading all of it into memory.

This is not the most efficient approach. Rather you can do something akin to:

```
    import codecs
    
    fileName='yourFile.text'
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
    with open(fileName, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
        print("Some unicode ⓓ⍶┳", file=fout)
```

Here we first open the file for writing in binary mode (note the `'wb'` paraemeter), write BOM and close the file right away. We then open the file and append to it (note the `'a'` parameter).

The resulting file will look like this:

> ```
>  00000000:  ef bb bf 53 6f 6d 65 20  75 6e 69 63 6f 64 65 20  ...Some unicode 
>  00000010:  e2 93 93 e2 8d b6 e2 94  b3 f0 9d 92 9c 0a -- --  ..............--
> ```