# Writing unicode with python - what is wrong with this character

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf-16le

With python 2.7 I am reading as unicode and writing as utf-16-le. Most characters are correctly interpreted. But some are not, for example, u'\u810a', also known as [unichr(33034)](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=810A&useutf8=false). The following code code does not write correctly:

```
import codecs
with open('temp.txt','w') as temp:
    temp.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)     
    text = unichr(33034)  # text = u'\u810a'
    temp.write(text.encode('utf-16-le'))
```

But either of these things, when replaced above, make the code work.

1. unichr(33033) and unichr(33035) work correctly.
2. 'utf-8' encoding (without BOM, [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)).

How can I recognize characters that won't write correctly, and how can I write a 'utf-16-le' encoded file with BOM that either prints these characters or some replacement?

Comment: Please define "incorrectly". What did you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: When unichr(33033) and unichr(33035) are used, the output is the correct Han character. But when I write unichr(33034), trying to write 脊, I get garbled text.

Comment: What are you using to view the file? What bytes are written, and what bytes did you expect?

Comment: I am using notepad++, which correctly views the character when it is pasted in. When writing the character with the above method, the hex values don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening the file in text mode, which means that [line-break characters/bytes will be translated to the local convention](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). Unfortunately the character you are trying to write includes a byte, `0A`, that is interpreted as a line break and does not make it to the file correctly.

Open the file in binary mode instead:

```
open('temp.txt','wb')
```

Comment: This answer does correct the problem. Many thanks! I'll accept once I debug completely.

Comment: Clear and concise - Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

@Joni's answer is the root of the problem, but if you use `codecs.open` instead it always opens in binary mode, even if not specified.  Using the `utf16` codec also automatically writes the BOM using native endian-ness as well:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('temp.txt','w','utf16') as temp:
    temp.write(u'\u810a')
```

Hex dump of `temp.txt`:

```
FF FE 0A 81
```

Reference: [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs.open#codecs.open)

Answer (score 0):

You're already using the codecs library. When working with that file, you should swap out using open() with codecs.open() to transparently handle encoding.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('temp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-16-le') as temp:
    temp.write(unichr(33033))
    temp.write(unichr(33034))
    temp.write(unichr(33035))
```

If you have a problem after that, you might have an issue with your viewer, not your Python script.

Comment: Looks good, but if I take your code (and add the "as temp" to the open line), I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I noticed that I used underscores instead of dashes for the encoding. Please try again.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing the BOM explicitly, just open the file with encoding="'utf-16' and the BOM will be written for you. See this answer for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/5726295/107660