# Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) as a python constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

It's not a real problem in practice, since I can just write `BOM = "\uFEFF"`; but it bugs me that I have to hard-code a magic constant for such a basic thing. [**Edit:** And it's error prone! I had accidentally written the BOM as `\uFFFE` in this question, and nobody noticed. It even led to an incorrect proposed solution.] Surely python defines it in a handy form somewhere?

Searching turned up a series of constants in the `codecs` module: `codecs.BOM`, `codecs.BOM_UTF8`, and so on. But these are `bytes` objects, not strings. Where is the real BOM?

This is for python 3, but I would be interested in the Python 2 situation for completeness.

Comment: Only way I know would be  `codecs.BOM.decode("utf-16-be")`, as far as I know using the constants from codecs will always give you bytes

Comment: Thanks, if the BOM really isn't defined anywhere else then this is the best answer I've seen yet.

Comment: Except your answer is wrong! :-) It converts the bytes into `\uFFFE`, which I had incorrectly written, but the BOM is `\uFEFF`. This variant is more verifiably correct: `codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode("utf-8")`. If this isn't proof that it would be useful to have the BOM available as a unicode string, I don't know what is...

Comment: Could your conversion be architecture-dependent? I think it would be, but I don't feel like verifying it. Anyway I think it's clear that getting the BOM should have been a no-brainer, but isn't...

Comment: `codecs.BOM.decode("utf-16-le")`, I used `be` to match the original output in your question

Comment: I figured... then I realized that it must be architecture-dependent as well :-). The answers to that [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5202648/699305) you linked to make this point.

Comment: yep, to get your endianness you can `import sys;sys.byteorder`

Comment: I wonder would `codecs.BOM_BE.decode("utf-16-be")` or `codecs.BOM_LE.decode("utf-16-le")`
 work regardless?

Comment: It _should,_ shouldn't it! I'd still go with decoding `BOM_UTF8`, it's easier to verify by inspection...

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. The `bytes` constants in `codecs` are what you should be using.

This is because you should never see a BOM in decoded text (i.e., you shouldn't encounter a string that actually encodes the code point `U+FEFF`). Rather, the BOM exists as a *byte pattern* at the start of a stream, and when you decode some `bytes` with a BOM, the `U+FEFF` isn't included in the output `string`. Similarly, the encoding process should handle adding any necessary BOM to the output `bytes`---it shouldn't be in the input `string`.

The only time a BOM matters is when either converting into or converting from `bytes`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What's your point? Nothing in my answer conflicts with those answers (some of which are quite poor). It's also consistent with the actual behaviour of the `utf-8-sig`, `utf-16`, and `utf-32` codecs (which automatically insert and strip BOMs).

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I do need to write a BOM, as in the question Padraic linked to. To write a byte string I'd have to open the file in binary mode, then reopen it in text mode to for the real contents. The BOM in string form is the only way to go.

Comment: PS. While you're right about its uses, the BOM is a real unicode codepoint, and it is indeed representable as a (unicode) string. I.e., it's not an out-of-band concept like parity or "end of file". Nothing prevents it from being included among python's constants.

Comment: It's representable, but its use as a proper Unicode character is discouraged: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom6

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use:

```
unicodedata.lookup('ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE')
```

but it's not as clean as what you already have

Comment: Haha, good point but as "magic constants" go this is arguably worse than just writing `\uFEFF`! :-) I know this is the codepoint that became the BOM, but that's a historical accident.