# text to csv file for japanese characters(Errors in arrangements)

Tags: python, csv, cjk

I wanted to convert my text file into csv file, however, my output seems to be very different from what I expected. Below are the examples:

text.txt (Encoding is "UTF-8")

text =

```
-0.00010712468871868001 gram_0:Coll:0::ん
-0.00010712468871868001 gram-1:Coll:-1::止まる
-0.00010712468871868001 gram-3:Coll:-3::帰る
-0.00010712468871868001 gram1:Coll:0::ん
-0.00010712468871868001 gram2:Coll:2::いく
-0.00010712468871868001 gram3:Coll:3::く
```

My code:

```
import csv

with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('log.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title', 'intro'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSMuD.png)

My expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZpDk.png)

It seems like I am getting quite a lot of ....... for the japanese characters. Could anyone please assist me on this?

Comment: Encoding issue? Are you on Windows? Try open text.txt using Notepad, click Save As..., and see what encoding shows up on the bottom of dialog.

Comment: @ChangQian Thank you for your response. I checked and it shows UTF8 and yes, I am on Windows.

Comment: first problem i found was in line.split(",") . There is no , in any line of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows use the BOM to determine encoding of text, but Python does not seem to auto-generate the BOM, and Windows may recognize the output file as ANSI. Try adding `out_file.write('\ufeff')` immediately after the inner `with`.

Source: [Adding BOM (unicode signature) while saving file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! It worked but how can I make the output the same as what I expected it to be? Everything was printed under the Title column

Comment: @JJson see Mohan's comment on your question - you should split on ' ' (space) instead of `,`

Comment: @JJson Don't forget to accept this answer. `*wink*`

Comment: How to accept this answer? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Can I ask? Why is the values have empty row after printing a new one? Is it possible to make it without empty row but all print after the previous?

Comment: @JJson What do you get now? Can you post another screenshot?

Comment: Found the answers. Thanks again