# Automating the steps of loading .csv file in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, automation

I have to load many `.csv` files into Excel on regular basis, something like pictorially shown [here (till step 9)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/prepare-your-excel-data-source-for-a-word-mail-merge-2d802b6b-a3a3-43e5-bb76-2cac7c68673e) -

*Excel* -> *Data* -> *From Text* -> *'Choose file by navigating to it's location and then clicking Import.'* -> *Text Import Wizard Step 1 of 3*.

These all the steps I have automated by writing a small python Script, where I make Python press the shortcut keys (imagine working without mouse and navigating in Excel by pressing shortcut keys).

```
import pyautogui
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe')
pyautogui.press('alt')
pyautogui.press('a')
pyautogui.press('f')
pyautogui.press('t')
pyautogui.typewrite(r'C:\Users\Jo\Revenue.txt')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

After running the above python script, I am presented with this *Import Wizard* window -

[image: Import Wizard]

Now, how can I make python choose `65001 : Unicode (UTF-8)` from the drop down? How can I specify in my python code to choose this encoding? Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to change the focus of the active element with tabulator?

Comment: I have no idea about it. Post it as a separate Question and may be someone with requisite knowledge will pick it.

Comment: Why not use an Excel automation library to do this? It will be far more reliable.

Comment: Anything that you could suggest?

Comment: @AndyG Please be kind enough not to insist on changing the title repeatedly, when OP has made it clear that he doesn't wish to do so. Let some prerogative remain with the OP. As a purist, if you still feel that it is fundamentally incorrect, then kindly report it to the moderators. That would be the right way of proceeding. Best regards,

Comment: @cph_sto I changed it once, not repeatedly, perhaps others also recognise the redundancy of starting or ending with Python in the title.

Comment: @AndyG I only saw your initials in the `Edited` and that's why I wrote the comment above, else I wouldn't have written it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will go about it. Adding `UTF-8 with BOM` to the file beginning will automatically instruct excel to select UTF in the `file origin` dropdown:

```
import codecs
import pyautogui

from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys

from time import sleep

filename = r'C:\path\excel_automation\data1.txt'
global content

def add_utf8_bom(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        content = f.read()
    with codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-8') as f2:
        f2.write('\ufeff')
        f2.write(content)

add_utf8_bom(filename)
app = Application().start(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE')
sleep(1)
#SendKeys('^n') #uncomment for excel 2016 or higher
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('alt')
pyautogui.press('a')
pyautogui.press('f')
pyautogui.press('t')
pyautogui.typewrite(filename)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29900075/4551984