# writing utf8 not working when opening file with notepad

Tags: python, utf-8

I am getting Chinese characters when I am trying to write a string to a file.  I heard you can fix this by changing to utf8 format but when I try to do that the file still opens in utf16?  On the bottom you can see it's UTF-16LE

```
f2 = io.open(pathtomyfile, mode="a+",encoding="utf8")
f2.write(MyString)
f2.close()
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're writing a BOM to the file, maybe it needs one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python

Comment: @RandomDavis Nice i think that worked

Comment: If you're curious, [here's an article about this issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts), and a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093) that goes into some technical details on what's happening with Notepad, or really, the `IsTextUnicode` function in Windows.