# Strange behavior when trying to create and write to a text file on macOS

Tags: python, macos, file-writing, f-string

I'm opening a plain text file, parsing it, and adding different lines to existing, empty string variables. I add these variables into a new variable that is a multi-line fstring. Trying to write the data to a new text file is not behaving as expected.

Reading the original file works fine. Text is properly parsed, variables populated.

The multi-line fstring variable seems fine. Prints normally. Even tried formatting it different ways which I show below.

When writing to a new file, that's where the strangeness starts. I've tried 2 ways:

1. Straight coding the `open` function with `w` or `w+`
2. Adding the above to a function and using that inside `main()`

The file is saved to disk with the correct name. Trying to `double-click` open in Finder produces nothing. `Right-click` to open produces nothing. Trying to move to trash with `command+delete` gives an error:

[image: Finder error dialogue]

It sounds like the file goes to trash, but as the file disappears from the folder a new one is created with the same name in its place.

If I try to open in TextMate via `File > Open`, it opens as a blank file with no errors.

Since I can't get rid of the file, I have to delete the directory and create the directory again with the same name, or force delete in Terminal using `rm`. Restarting the system does not help. Relaunching Finder does nothing. Saving text files from other apps works fine. Directory is `chmod 755`.

If I copy an existing text file into the output directory, rename it to what the file is expected to be named, and let python overwrite the contents, it doesn't work either. The file modification date changes (and I see the file "blink" in Finder) but the contents remain the same. However, the file is not corrupted and opens normally.

If I do the same but delete the text inside of the copied file first, then run the script, python writes no data to the file, I can't open it by double-clicking on it, and I get `error -43` again with the odd non-trashing behavior.

The strangest thing is this: if I add another `with open()` at the end of the script, and open the file that was just created and supposedly written to, and print its contents, the contents print. It's like when the script ends the file contents are being removed or its being corrupted somehow. Tried to close the file inside the script even though it's not needed, but same behavior persists.

### Code:

Here's the code for writing:

```py
FORMAT='utf-8'
OUTPUT_DIR = '/Path/To/SaveFolder'

# as a function
def write_to_file(content, fpath, name):
    the_file = os.path.join(fpath, name)
    with open(the_file, 'w+', encoding=FORMAT) as t:
        t.write(content)

def main():

    print(f" Writing File...\n")

    filename = f"{pcode}_{author}_{title}_text.txt"
    write_to_file(multiline_var, OUTPUT_DIR, filename)

# or hard coded in main()
def main():

    print(f" Writing File...\n")

    filename = f"{pcode}_{author}_{title}_text.txt"
    the_file = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, filename)
    with open(the_file, 'w+', encoding=FORMAT) as t:
        t.write(multiline_var)
```

I have tried using `w` `w+` `wt` and `wt+` and with and without `encoding='utf-8'`

Here is an example of multi-line fstring variable:

```py
# using triple quotes
multiline_var = f"""
[PROJ-{pcode}] {full_title} by {author}

{description}

{URL}

{DIVIDER_1}
{TEXT_BLURB}

Some text here and then {SOME_MORE_TEXT}"
{DIVIDER_1}

{SOME_LINK}
"""

# or inside parens

multiline_var = (
    f"[PROJ-{pcode}] {full_title} by {author}\n"
    f"{description}\n\n"
    f"{URL}\n"
    f"{DIVIDER_1}\n"
    f"{TEXT_BLURB}\n\n"
    f"Some text here and then {SOME_MORE_TEXT}\n"
    f"{DIVIDER_1}\n\n"
    f"{SOME_LINK}"
)
```

Using exiftool on the text file shows the following, so it looks the data is there but must be corrupted:

```sh
File Size                       : 1797 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:12:31 15:55:39-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:12:31 15:58:13-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:12:31 15:55:39-05:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TXT
File Type Extension             : txt
MIME Type                       : text/plain
MIME Encoding                   : utf-8
Byte Order Mark                 : No
Newlines                        : Unix LF
Line Count                      : 55
Word Count                      : 181
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. VScode shows no syntax errors in the script. There are no errors in Terminal when running the script. Have I made some simple mistake in the above code? Maybe the fstring variable is causing a problem?

Comment: What does `cat filename` in the terminal show? This looks like a bug in file opening in finder/MacOS rather than something specific in your python, which looks  fairly standard.

Comment: @match Interesting. `cat filename` actually shows the correct contents are in the file and formatted properly. Any idea what might be messed up in the OS that could cause this?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: @JohnGordon Seems to be 644 (-rw-r--r--). If you check the exiftool output I posted, you'll see there is no byte order mark. All my other txt files seem to have a byte order mark. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Is it owned by a userid other than yourself?

Comment: @JohnGordon no. User is set properly. Get Info in Finder shows identical to my other files. Also I edited above comment regarding byte order mark.

Comment: I just tried to add BOM using method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43016715/3927293) `t.write('\ufeff')` before adding my content. exiftool sees the BOM, but still seems corrupted.

Comment: What is the actual, literal name of one of these files? It seems people have hit this with either unexpected characters in the name, or a very long filename.

Comment: @bnaecker Happy new year! File name is like `0001_LastName_First_TheTitleOfSomething_text.txt` and could be a little longer or shorter depending. I will test it out. What is the remedy? To create a short named file and then use a system command to change the name or something?

Comment: @liquidRock I'm not sure, but the "solution" is probably, "Don't do that." If the name doesn't have any odd characters in it, I'm not sure about the length issue, since the OS shouldn't even let you _create_ a file with a name that's too long. Sorry, it was a random guess. You might have more luck on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @bnaecker Well I'll be damned, it worked. I have way longer file names for some project (images, video frames, etc) and similar with images saved with Python. For whatever reason, writing to a text file with Python corrupts it. I'll post an answer. Thanks for the tip. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bnaecker for leading me to the solution to this problem.

It appeared that when creating/writing to a text file with a long name, Python can corrupt it. Not sure why, as I save long names for images with Python image libraries all the time. Using a short name like "MyFile.txt" it worked just fine, but that was a red herring.

I have updated this post with my journey to the final solution for using the long names that are needed for my project, though I'm not sure why the problem exists.

### First Attempts:

So far creating using a short name and then renaming to a long one.... attempts have failed. I did notice that python is locking the file it creates and never unlocks it. Not sure if this is the problem. Setting `chflags` with `os.system('chflags nouchg')` command does not work, not even with sudo, and not even in the Terminal doing it manually.

1. Using `os.rename()` in Python corrupts the file
2. Using `os.system('mv oldFile.txt newFile.txt')` corrupts the file
3. Manually using `mv` command in Terminal corrupts the file
4. Manually changing the filename in the Finder does not (wtf?)

I kept looking for workarounds but nothing did the job.

### Round 2:

Progress!

After much tinkering, I discovered a hidden character inside the file. I ran `cat /path/longfilename.txt` in Terminal, selected and copied the output and pasted into VScode. Here is what I saw:

[image]

Somehow a hidden character is getting into the project code number.

Pasting it into a Unicode search engine it came up as a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` also known in Unicode as `EF BB BF`. However, when pasting this symbol into TextMate it shows up as `<U+FEFF>` which is?...

***The Byte Order Mark!***

Opening a normal utf-8 text file in a hex editor also shows the files starting with `EFBBBF` for the BOM.

Now, the text file being read and parsed at first has no blank lines to start the file, so I added a line break, and also tried adding some spaces. This time when writing the file I could open it, however, after sending it to the trash, the same behavior occurred and the file was broken again. It seems that because other corrupted versions were in the trash, it added the symbol back to the file name for some reason.

So what appears to be happening, for whatever reason, when Python opens the text file I'm parsing that has no line break at the top, it *seems* to be grabbing the `BOM` from the file and adding that to the first variable which is grabbing the first line of the text file. Since that text is a number code that starts the file name, the BOM symbol is being added to the file name as well as the code inside the text file.

Just... wow

### The Current Solution:

I have to leave a blank line at the start of the text file that I'm opening and parsing and a simple line break won't do it. I have no idea why this is. I added some spaces for good measure because randomly the BOM would be added to the variable and filename again. So far (knock on wood) as long as the first line of that initial file has some spaces and then a line break, and previous corrupted files have been deleted from the trash, a long file name can be used for all the files I'm creating and writing to without any problems.

This corruption even persists if I remove the encoding flag from both of the open functions I'm using (one to read and parse, the other to create and write).

If anyone knows why this is happening, please share. I've never seen it mentioned before. I'm not sure if it's a python 3.8 bug, a mac OS bug, the way TextMate wrote the original file, or a combination of these.

### Correct Solution:

Thanks to @tripleee for the proper way to handle this, as I don't remember seeing this before, though I haven't been using python for very long.

In order to ignore the BOM, reading in the text file to be parsed with an `encoding='utf-8-sig'` does the job. Seems to be why it exists. :)

Problem solved.

Comment: _Removing_ the `encoding` keyword seems like an extremely odd attempt to work around the problem. Try using `encoding='utf-8-sig'` for reading, but plain `'utf-8'` for writing. This will only drop a _file-initial_ BOM, though. In the general case, `content = content.replace('\ufeff', '')` will obviously remove any interspersed BOMs.

Comment: I was just testing everything I could think of to see how it reacted. I'll give the `utf-8-sig` a try for the read to see if that helps. 

Comment: Yep, this is the solution. Never saw (or noticed) `utf-8-sig` before. Will update my answer. Thanks