# How can Ghostscript enable Unicode in Outline / Bookmarks?

Tags: python, encoding, ghostscript

I am post processing a pdf file in order to add an index. For that I use

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
-sOutputFile=newfile_indexed.pdf index.info \
-f original_unindexed_file.pdf
```

The input file `index.info` is encoded in utf-8. Entries that include umlauts (ö,ä,ü) are not shown correctly in the index, but instead are represented by unreadable strings (as we often see it when there is an encoding misunderstanding).

Any idea what encoding I need or how I can tell ghostscript the encoding so that it understands?

**Minimal example for index.info file**

```
[/Page 1 /Count 0 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title (Lügenbaron) /OUT pdfmark
```

In this case "Lügenbaron" will become "L[some string]genbaron" in the pdf viewer.

**Atempting to UTF-16BE encoding with BOM**

I tried:

```
with open(filepath, "w+", encoding="UTF-16BE") as f:
    f.write('\ufeff')
    # write rest of data
```

because I saw the f.write part here: [Adding BOM (unicode signature) while saving file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python)

This doesn't work and exits with an unrecoverable error.

**UTF-16 without BOM**

```
FORMAT = "[/Page {page} /Count {count} /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title ({title}) /OUT pdfmark"
with open(f"{filepath}-output", "w+") as f:
        #f.write('\ufeff')
        for entry in entries:
            title_encoded = entry[2].encode(encoding="utf-16-BE")
            f.writelines(f"{FORMAT.format(page=entry[0], count=entry[1], title=title_encoded)}\n")
```

Example output in file:

```
[/Page 4 /Count 0 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title (b'\x00V\x00o\x00r\x00w\x00o\x00r\x00t') /OUT pdfmark
```

In pdf:
[image]

**UTF-16 with BOOM working mostly**
I used `.hex().upp()` to get the necessary formatting. An example line looks now like this:

```
[/Page 7 /Count 0 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title <FEFF0031002E00200052006500670065006C006E> /OUT pdfmark
```

I noticed that the brackets `()` are no longer needed and are shown in the pdf when used, so I removed them.

It also with the new and shorter command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o indexed.pdf lesezeichen.asc -q original_file.pdf
```

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you have in 'index.info'. If that's a PostScript program then it can't be using UTF-8 because PostScript doesn't support UTF-8. It's probably StandardEncoding which, for the bottom 127 characters, matches UTF-8.  You need to encode the font so that the desired glyphs are present at the correct Encoding positions. This isn't a Ghostscript problem (or so it seems) it is a problem with the PostScript program. You should post the content of index.info, it won't be possible to offer any more detailed information without it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how the index creation works. I found the code and have used it in the past, but I haven't used text with umlauts before. Can you describe in an answer maybe how to "encode the font" and what you mean by that?

Comment: Briefly, no, it's complicated. John Deubert's excellent Acumen Journal has two articles on the subject in November and December of 2001 here: http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html However.... what you have there is a pdfmark, which is a Distiller-only PostScript extension. You **can** put Unicode in that (because its a PostScript extension) but you have to use UTF-16BE with the correct BOM. Otherwise you must use PDFDocEncoding where uumlaut is character code 252 (oxfc, octal 0374) see Appendix D2 of the PDF (1.7) Reference Manual.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I added what I've tried above. Maybe a hint how to add the correct BOM if that is possible.

Comment: This [/Page 1 /Count 0 /View [/XYZ null null null] /Title <FEFF00FC> /OUT pdfmark produces an Outline with a node whose title is the single letter u umlaut. You need to create a hex string rather than a standard string, so <> rather than (), you need to supply the BOM, so FEFF and you need to make all the character codes 16 bits, so 00FC is character code FC which is Unicode (and as it happens PDFDocEncoding) for the u with an umlaut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supplementary file may be UTF-8 but the Data must be in 16BE format
so within < `FEFF` is the ByteOrderMark and `0028` = `(` in UTF-16BigEndian thus `0029` is `)` before the `>` closing bracket

```
[/Title <FEFF0028004C00FC00670065006E006200610072006F006E0029> /Count 0 /Color 1 1 1 /Page 1 /View [/XYZ null null null]  /OUT pdfmark
```

[image]

I have not tried other combinations to say it is correct method for other facets of adding outline and my test file ran but input was bad so cant say if bad output was due to method.

I ran again both with a simple clean image.pdf and tried another file with known bad text, both worked perfectly as above. So I think the 1st bad text input was the culprit for bad text body (the outline entry itself was perfect).

Your command could probably be shortened [see here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#o_option)

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o indexed.pdf lesezeichen.asc -q original_file.pdf
```

old adobe link about bookmark (**OUT**line) structure was opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/html2015/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2Fpdfmark_Basic%2FBookmarks_OUT.htm including

> If Unicode, the string must begin with `<FEFF>`. For example, the Unicode string for (ABC) is `<FEFF004100420043>`.

That was June 2008 version and Current (2021) pdfmark link is https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_pdfmark.pdf

Comment: When I convert to "utf-16-be" my output is in hex. And when I create the pdf it is still printed as hex. What are you doing different?

Comment: This works mostly, but the `&` symbol is still not shown correctly.

Comment: You are correct. The "&" symbol was simply not shown correctly in the pdf viewer (zathura). I tried a different pdf-viewer and it works. Than you very much!
The example line above didn't include an `&` symbol. It was a different line and my bad.