# Excel to CSV conversion causing unexpected output in CSV file (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert an Excel file (data4.xlsx) to a CSV file using Python and pandas. However, I'm encountering unexpected content in the CSV file. Here's what the content looks like:

```
Per default, this worksheet is working only with an Excel English version
If you want to use it with an other version you need to indicate in the cells "row initial" and "column initial" at the bottom of this worksheet 
the initials used in your Excel version.

How to find these initials?
First go to Tools/Options:
And check what letters are used for the old "row column" style (in French version is: "L1C1", in German version is "Z1S1", in Polish version is "W1K1").

If your Excel show "R1C1" you have nothing to do.
If your style is L1C1 you have to input L for row initial and C for column initial

Row initial
Column initial

You do not need to select the option "reference style" in Excel
```

I'm unsure why this content is appearing in my CSV file and how to prevent it. I want my CSV file to contain only the data from the Excel file without any additional content.

What I've tried - very early stage of implementation, but I've already stopped because of that weird output. My excel sheets contains diacritics (in standard it's in Polish but contains english words) - also my program working completely fine for a .xls files, only when working with .xlsx I'm getting this weird output in csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Data/data4.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel('Data/data4.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df.to_csv('wtf.csv', index=True)
```

When attempting to transform my Excel file (data4.xlsx) to a CSV file using Python and pandas, the resulting CSV file contains unexpected content as shown above. How can I ensure that only the data from the Excel file is included in the CSV file without any additional content?

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: After looking at multiple questions on different fora this can possibly be solved by giving an encoding to the csv. [See here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-csv-file-that-uses-UTF-8-character-encoding/m-p/1311587#M148980). Then you could implement one of the options provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202648/adding-bom-unicode-signature-while-saving-file-in-python).